# Notifications for new post in Wordpress

Tags: ios, notifications, wordpress, apple-push-notifications

Wordpress has a notification button on top right in admin panel which displays notifications when:
1. Someone commented on your post
2. Someone follow your blog, like your post or reblogs your post.
3. You get any awards like n likes on a post.

Can this functionality be altered so that I get notifications only when I create a new post. I know this sound awkward but I need to send push notifications to all users of my iOS app when i create a new post. The latter part i.e. sending push notifications to iOS when a new notification arrives is done already.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wordpress API has hook, which is called whenever a new post is inserted: [Wordpress Doc](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post)

You could use this hook with the help of [APNS-PHP](https://code.google.com/p/apns-php/) to send pushes to all of the registered devices whenever a new post is inserted.

A good tutorial about how to create custom Wordpress Plugins is available [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch--net-2668)

Another lazier alternative would be to just use an existing plugin like [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-parse-push-service/) for example (for this plugin you need a [Parse.com](http://pars.com) account.)

Comment: Yes that was my main plan, but most of the web hosts block access to 2196 and other ports that APNS uses. I have made a request to open them. thanks anyways.